# AngularJS how to wait for value to be populated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have code like this in a directive:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    var formCtrl = elm.inheritedData("$formController");
    formCtrl[attrs.inputReference]// <- error formCtrl undefined
    console.log(formCtrl); // <- viewed in console is not undefined and has expected value
```

I know that chrome will log the object as a reference and that it might change by the time I view it but how can I wait for it to be populated before proceeding?

I know that when I have problem with attributes not being ready I can call `$observe` on them but how do I do something similar in this case?

*Use case*
An input matching validator where I want to push a $parser onto each model controller.

**Update**
I could $scope.$watch and do everything once that $formController is there. My question I guess then is that really the right way to do it?

Comment: I think you want to inject $formController as a dependency of your directive.

Comment: The way you are trying to access the controller seems questionable to me. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish and maybe we can guide you.

Comment: ...but you can probably do: `scope.on(function(){ if(elm.inheritedData("$formController") {//do your stuff;} });`

Comment: @jkinkead: the controller is not a service. right? How would the injector find the instance to inject?

Comment: You pass in ctrl to your link function, presumably with a require. Is that not the formController?